# How to restart a Network Stream after a SocketException

Tags: c#, networkstream

I have a piece of code that reads a JSON stream from a server on the public internet.  I am trying to make the connection a little more robust by catching the exception and trying to restart it on a given interval but I haven't been able to figure out how to restart it.

My stream code is as follows

```
TcpClient connection = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
NetworkStream stream = connection.GetStream();

thread = new Thread(ProcessStream);
thread.Start(stream);
```

My ProcessStream method is

```
private void ProcessStream(object stream)
{
    Stream source = (NetworkStream)stream;
    byte[] line;
    int count;
    const int capacity = 300;
    ReadState readState;
    while ((readState = ReadStreamLine(source, out line, out count, capacity)) != ReadState.EOF && _stopFeed == false)
    {
        if (readState != ReadState.Error && count > 4)
        {
            byte[] line1 = new byte[count];
            Array.Copy(line, line1, count);
            Process(line1); // return ignored in stream mode                    
        }
        else
        {
            ReadFail(line, count);
        }
    }
}
```

and my ReadStream function takes the stream s, does an s.ReadByte and then catches the exception when the network connection is broken.  It is here that I am not sure how to try and restart the stream on a timed basis.  It does not restart automatically when the network is restored.

Comment: Hi, This seems like a perfect candidate for a retry strategy. There is a very good one with the latest Patterns & Practices. 

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/transient-fault-handling

Although it is focussed on Azure, the issue is the same. You want to identify transient errors and execute a relevent retry strategy.

Comment: Where is `line1` defined? Is the objective of `ProcessStream` to simply aggregate some data, or does it have side effects?

Comment: As you have written these functions, your question cannot be answered. If a `NetworkStream` encounters an error, that's it -- the stream is no longer usable. You have to close it and retry the entire request. Since `ProcessStream` cannot recover from the error, it shouldn't try -- it has to let the exception bubble up and let the caller handle it. You'll need to move up to a higher level for your retries.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Can you point to some code as to better handle a json stream in a way that would allow me to restart it?

Comment: Why not wrap your header stream into a function that returns `Boolean`? If the function wrapper is unsuccessful then retry until successful or until specified number of retries using `do..while`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have to do a line-by-line read in the first place? Why not just `WebClient.DownloadString` the whole thing and if that fails, try again? Piecemeal downloading will not get you restartability -- nothing will get you that, short of ranged requests (as @Hans points out below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you instantiate your `TcpClient` before you start your method. So, in order to restart your stream, you need to re-instantiate or re-initialize your connection stream before trying again.

```
try 
{
     // Do something
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Caught your exception, might be ideal to log it too
    // Have a count, if count is less than goal
    // Call your method again
    if (count < 5)
    {
        // re-initialize or re-instantiate connection
        TcpClient connection = new TcpClient(host, port);
        NetworkStream stream = connection.GetStream();
        ProcessStream(stream);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible.  It is like you calling your friend on the phone and he hangs up in the middle of a conversation.  No matter how long you wait, you'll never hear from him again.  All you can do is hang-up the phone and dial the number again.  Unless the server supports restartable downloads (use HttpWebRequest.AddRange), you'll have to download the json again from the beginning.

If this happens a lot, so it can't be explained by the server going offline or getting overloaded, do keep in mind that the server might well be doing this on purpose.  Usually because you exceeded some kind of quota.  Talk to the server owner, they typically have a paid plan to allow you to use more resources.

Comment: This is used in an environment where the internet can go down, and we are trying to handle that gracefully.  To use your metaphor I just want to automatically call my friend back and pick up with him blabbing away.

Comment: No, he hang up when he couldn't hear you anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You coculd at first add your stream to a static list of running streams and after finishing reading remove it from there.
Remember to use locking!

Then in the NetworkGone-Catch you can copy your list to a "todoAfterNetworkIsUpAgain"-List and start a timer that checks for network and after your network is up again restarts reading the streams again.

Answer (score -2):

**This Might look a bit tuff but its not the case.**

Use Recursion and threading in a better way and your problem might get resolved

For Recursion
http://www.dotnetperls.com/recursion

For Threading
Take a look to msdn documentation or take consepts from albahari